# Pandas select value by multiple columns

Tags: pandas

For this simple dataframe

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([
    ['a', 5, 9],
    ['b', 4, 61],
    ['c', 24, 9]],
    columns=['name', 'attr11', 'attr12'])
```

I can select 61 by

```
df1.loc[(df1['name'] == 'b'), 'attr12'].item()
```

How could that be changed to horizontally query for name == b and attr11 == 4 ?

Comment: `df1.query('name == "b" and attr11 == 4')`. You can use `@var` inside the query if you need to pass a variable instead of a constant.

Comment: also `df1['name'].eq('b) & df1['attr11'].eq(4)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df1.loc[(df1['name'] == 'b') & (df1['attr11'] == 4), 'attr12'].item()
```

Comment: I thought I tried it already. However that works :-)